# Seeing if a character in line a is also in line b

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to write a python code see to if a character in line a is also in line b but not in the same position. I do not know where to get started

for example :
line a = 1365
line b = 3487

How would I write a code that tells me that 3 is in line a and in line b but not in the same position

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: My code so far is                                                  
user_guess=input('Guess a four digit number: ')
correct_number=random.sample(range(0,9),4)                                          for i in user_guess:
    if i in correct_number is True and user_guess[i]!=currect_number[i]:

Comment: Can you edit all of your code into the question?